# Combining Image and Table Vertically

Tags: floats, captions, positioning, subfloats, floatrow

What is the best way to combine an image and a table vertically like the following layout?

```
 ______________
|     Image    |
|______________|
  a) Our Image
 ______________
|     Table    |
|______________|
  d) Our Table
```

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/how-to-layout-four-figures-with-floatrow-two-of-them-vertically) related. However, it is discussing multiple figures and not a figure and table.

Comment: Technically there is no difference between an image and a `tabular`. Don't know why you're labelling it (a) and (d) though.

Answer (score 1):

Although you do not mention this aspect in your question, I guess that the main problem, here, is to get the right entries in the list of figures and list of tables.  Your friend, in this case, is the `caption` package, as the following compilable example shows.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{caption}    % essential
\usepackage{booktabs}   % just provides better rules for tables
\usepackage{graphicx}   % for figures
\usepackage{mwe}        % dummy text, easier access to example figures
\usepackage{hyperref}   % to check that it works too

\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom}
% you asked for captions following tables
\captionsetup[table] {position=bottom}



\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{Our example}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = .5]{image-a}
    \caption{A figure with the letter~``A'''}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

Some text that refers to figure~\ref{fig:a} and to figure~\ref{fig:b}.

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
        Alpha & Beta & Gamma  \\
        \midrule
        1 & 2 & 3  \\
        4 & 5 & 6  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The first table}
    \label{tab:first}
\end{table}

Some text that refers to table~\ref{tab:first} and to table~\ref{tab:second}.

\lipsum[5-8]

\begin{figure}[tbp] % here "figure" could also be "table"
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = .25]{image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure with the letter~``B'''}
    \label{fig:b}
    \bigskip % for example; or "\vspace{...}"
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
        Delta & Epsilon & Zeta  \\
        \midrule
        10 & 20 & 30  \\
        40 & 50 & 60  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{The second table}
    \label{tab:second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```